# openVidu - connectionDestroyed / sessionDisconnected event doesn't trigger when websocket connection lost because of network problem

Tags: javascript, webrtc, openvidu

Publisher doesn't notify when connection is destroyed or diconnected. In Openvidu docs, they suggest `connectionDestroyed` & `sessionDisconnected` event but it doesn't trigger anymore. How can i solve this issue ? From publisher side i need to inform publisher while network is lost and connection is destroyed.

```
session.on('connectionDestroyed', reason => {
    //...
    //Doesn't trigger
});

session.on('sessionDisconnected', reason => {
    //...
    //Doesn't trigger
});
```

#### Updated:

`sessionDisconnected` event is invoked when i reconnect successfully or gracefully close the session. But i need to inform publisher immediately when internet connection is lost.

Answer (score 0):

### Not sure if Openvidu has changed the event names but you can also try following as per doc - [here](https://openvidu.io/docs/reference-docs/REST-API/)

```
session.on('streamDestroyed', reason => {
    //...
});
```

Comment: I tested almost every event, May be something wrong with local environment. My project need internet connection to run successfully. When i turn off wifi for testing, my project is also unable to run - may be this is the reason why event is not triggered. Not sure...
Everything is all right from server side, i deployed my server on cloud.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
session.on('streamCreated', event => { }
```

and

```
session.on('sessionDisconnected', (event) => { }
```

Both are working for me.